# Enable iOS notification center, but keep the status bar hidden?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I want my application to not show the [iOS status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUXpi.png). I can do this in **AppDelegate.m** like so:

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  application.statusBarHidden = YES;
  return YES;
}
```

This hides the status bar great, but makes the [iOS notification center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3GRL.jpg) and the [iOS control center](http://9to5mac.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/21.png) take 2 swipes to pull in. I do not want [this behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2aaS.jpg).

Any help would be fantastic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry for the half-hearted answer, but I don't have enough rep to comment. Basically your app thinks it's in fullscreen mode, and that requires a 'double' swipe to bring up control center og notif-center. So you'll have to find a way to overwrite that default fullscreen behaviour